# cannot execute something from variable vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript

the data of C:\highlight2.txt is :
"document.all.status1.innerText = 'component failure'"

```html
<script>
    set oFile=oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\highlight2.txt",1)
       text=oFile.ReadAll
       oFile.Close
       arrLines = Split(text, vbCrLf)
       dim cmds
       For Each strLine in arrLines
       if strLine = "" Then
       else
        strLine
       end if
       next

    </script>

    <input value="component check progress" type="text" id="Status1" >
```

i need to change input field from text, but its not work, input text id was variable. thanks, the help i really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you need to use [`Execute` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2(v=vs.84).aspx) as follows: `Execute strLine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string containing code to execute, you need to [execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2(v=vs.84).aspx) it:

```
>> For Each s In Split("WScript.Echo 1|WScript.Echo 2", "|")
>>     WScript.Echo "Statement:", s
>>     Execute s
>>   On Error Resume Next
>>     s
>>     WScript.Echo Err.Description
>>   On Error GoTo 0
>>     WScript.Echo "-----------"
>> Next
>>
Statement: WScript.Echo 1
1
Type mismatch
-----------
Statement: WScript.Echo 2
2
Type mismatch
-----------
>>
```